# Sharing C# WIndows Form Application within Local Network

Tags: c#, windows, forms, networking

Let's say I have a local network with three computers. I would like my windows form application to be accessible in comp1, comp2 and comp3. Where should I save my database and tables to be shared with these three computers? Should I install my form application each computer?

Any answers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's an interesting question, but it's way too broad for this site's Q&A format. There have been books written about architecture decisions like this, I suggest you read one or two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously had the same question.

I ended up mapping a network drive on a PC and had this running 24/7 and installed the application on all other PC's.

This seems to work ok as long as you are not pulling too much data from the database as it gets very slow and drops connection frequently.

Hope this helps